# Install working rosbag package for Jupyter Notebook (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

[image: rosbag error on Notebook]

Trying to plot the data from ros topics in a rosbag file. My system by default had Python 2.7 and I installed Python 3.5 just to work with Jupyter notebooks.

Now I have installed several packages twice, once for Python 2 and again for Python 3. Although most packages are compatible with both versions of Python, I am beginning to wonder if all the ros packages are compatible here.

For the image in this question, initially I was getting an error 'No module named 'rosbag_pandas'', then I installed it with pip3. Now I am facing the error shown in the image with regards to rosbag. I have searched high and low for a quick fix but to no avail. I read online that some packages only work with either Python 2.7 or with Python 3.5. Is that what's happening here?

FYI I have installed pyrosbag with pip and pip3 both. Still facing this issue. Could really use some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and found a workaround for me. Basically, on top of the usual python 3 installation, install a python 2 kernel for jupyter notebook, as described [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html), as follows:

```
python2 -m pip install pip
python2 -m pip install --upgrade ipykernel
python2 -m ipykernel install
```

Not sure if there is indeed a python 3 package for rosbag but using the python 2 kernel you can import rosbag files to save them in another format for further processing in python 3.